# I created a Xamarin UWP app, but for some reason it's blank. How can I get my Xamarin UI to appear in the UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

With a Xamarin Android app, the UI doesn't need to be defined twice, once in the Xamarin project and once in the Android project; the Android project seems to be able to see the changes made to the UI in the Xamarin project and adjust itself accordingly. However when I create a UWP app with this MainPage.xaml:

```
<forms:WindowsPage
    x:Class="ApiPrototypeClientMobile.Uwp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ApiPrototypeClientMobile.Uwp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</forms:WindowsPage>
```

it is blank, as if I need to redefine the UI from scratch or maybe I set something up wrong so it's not getting loaded properly. Do I actually need to redefine the entire UI for the app all over again for UWP, or did I just set it up wrong?

Comment: Please check if  uwp native project has invoked  `LoadApplication()` in MainPage Class Code behind

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do anything specific to support UWP. It may happen that some plugins don't support UWP and that may be the cause. Or that the layout is impossible as some UWP controls have padding by default unlike on other platforms. It could be various things, so you need to check piece by piece on what is blocking your UI to appear.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have much experience with Xamarin or UWP - what pieces might need to be checked?